# Select first group of 10 for each day (removing duplicate records)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table called BillingInformation with the following columns:
id, clientId, type, order, value, timestamp

id is an artificial key
For each clientId on a particular date there will be 10 types e.g.

```
clientId   type              order    timestamp
1          Outstanding AR    0        2012-09-24 10:45:28.557
1          Est. Days In AR   1        2012-09-24 10:45:28.580
1          ...               2        2012-09-24 10.45.28.603
1          ...               3        2012-09-24 10.45.28.620  
1          ...               4        2012-09-24 10.45.28.630  
1          ...               5        2012-09-24 10.45.28.653
1          ...               6        2012-09-24 10.45.28.697
1          ...               7        2012-09-24 10.45.28.717
1          ...               8        2012-09-24 10.45.28.727
1          ...               9        2012-09-24 10.45.28.727
2          Outstanding AR    0        ...
2          Est. Days In AR   1        ...
(cont. 8 more rows for client 2)
```

My issue is that I have some clientIds where the 10 entries are in the database more than once and I just want to select just 10 (where order = 0 through 9) per client.

Here is my situation now:

```
clientId   type              order    timestamp
1          Outstanding AR    0        2012-09-24 10:45:28.557
1          Est. Days In AR   1        2012-09-24 10:45:28.580
1          ...               2        2012-09-24 10.45.28.603
1          ...               3        2012-09-24 10.45.28.620  
1          ...               4        2012-09-24 10.45.28.630  
1          ...               5        2012-09-24 10.45.28.653
1          ...               6        2012-09-24 10.45.28.697
1          ...               7        2012-09-24 10.45.28.717
1          ...               8        2012-09-24 10.45.28.727
1          ...               9        2012-09-24 10.45.28.727
1          Outstanding AR    0        2012-09-24 10:45:28.557
1          Est. Days In AR   1        2012-09-24 10:45:28.580
1          ...               2        2012-09-24 10.45.28.603
1          ...               3        2012-09-24 10.45.28.620  
1          ...               4        2012-09-24 10.45.28.630  
1          ...               5        2012-09-24 10.45.28.653
1          ...               6        2012-09-24 10.45.28.697
1          ...               7        2012-09-24 10.45.28.717
1          ...               8        2012-09-24 10.45.28.727
1          ...               9        2012-09-24 10.45.28.727
2          Outstanding AR    0        ...
2          Est. Days In AR   1        ...
```

(cont. 8 more rows for client 2)
(cont. 10 rows for client 3)
(and so on...)

No matter how many times the records 0 through 9 are repeated for client 1 for the day of 2012-09-14 (disregarding hours minutes seconds and milliseconds), I just want to select just one group of 10 along with the other records.  So if any client has duplicated sets of 10 for the same month day and year, I just want one group of 10 for that month day and year.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select id, clientId, type, [order], value, timestamp
from
(
  select *, row_number() over (partition by clientId, [order],
                                            datediff(d,0,timestamp)
                               order by timestamp desc) rn
  from BillingInformation
) X
where rn=1
```

Comment: This worked as well and seemed to have faster execution time than @GilM's answer. This is why I marked this as the correct answer. Both produced the correct results.  Thanks!

Comment: FYI, that's because it doesn't need to go back to the BillingInformation table, nor does it rely on the implicit assumption that id is unique. Thanks for accepting the answer!

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ClientId, CAST([timestamp] AS date), [order] ORDER BY [timestamp]) as rn
FROM BillingInformation
)
SELECT b.*
FROM BillingInformation b
JOIN CTE c on c.id = b.id and c.rn=1
```